# fetch --nohooks --no-history chromium throws error : depot_tools/fetch: line 8: exec: python: not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, fetch, chromium, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to check out code from chromium directory in Ubuntu 18.04 machine and getting this error: "python not found".
I have installed python2.7 recently using below commands:

```sh
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/Python-2.7.16.tgz 
sudo tar xzf Python-2.7.16.tgz
cd Python-2.7.16
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

`which python2.7` yields:

> /usr/local/bin/python2.7

So I changed the Python alias with: `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

Now, even after this when I am trying to fetch chromium, it says

> "line 8: exec: python: not found".
>
> ~/chromium$ fetch --nohooks --no-history  chromium
>
> depot_tools/fetch: line 8: exec: python: not found

Note: I have already added /usr/local/bin/python2.7 to PATH variable.

Adding output of echo$PATH

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/quic/depot_tools:/usr/local/bin/python2.7

Comment: Thanks Das Geek for formatting!

Comment: Can you add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining an alias is limited to the currently running shell only. It is not inherited to subprocesses.

In order to have `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` as your default python, you have to have a symlink somewhere on your path which points to there.

Example: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/bin/python` if your `~/bin` is on the `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks! adding symbolic links resolved my issue. > ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3

Comment: @JackR Now that's a quite bad idea, because it lets the symlink for python3 point to python2.7. Better name it python2 or python. And better don't put it into `/usr/bin`, that's made for the package managers. Here as well, `/usr/local/bin/` should be the place to use.

Comment: Thanks! I will make the changes.